# Static Methods and ThreadSafe Applications

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, thread-safety

I'm currently transitioning my GAE application from the Python 2.5 runtime to the Python 2.7 runtime with "ThreadSafe" enabled.

Currently my data access methods look something like:

```
@staticmethod
def GetByPermaLinkId(permaLinkId):
    result = memcache.get("entry-by-permalink-id:" + permaLinkId)

    if result is None:
        result = db.get(permaLinkId)
        memcache.set("entry-by-permalink-id:" + permaLinkId, result)

    return result
```

So I suppose I have two questions.

1. Is my data access method completely ridiculous?
2. Is my data access method okay for use in "ThreadSafe" applications?

I'm super new to App Engine and Python developement, feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The easy way to recognize something that may not be threadsafe is to look for "mutable shared state". That is, it has to be modified by code (true here) and shared (not true, since the variables you define are scoped only to the function they're called in).

Comment: Hello. I have published an analysis of threadsafe for GAE here devcon5.blogspot.com (although for GAE/J) and would very much appreciate any comments or additional questions I should cover. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Caching frequently requested data is a good idea, however you really want to take a look at  the Python Style Guide PEP8 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
2. Yes, your method is ok. Thread safety in python is usually an issue of multiple threads accessing shared data. You are using memcache to handle the shared data and memcache in this use case is thread safe as far as I know. Would you instead have tried to cache your result in a global variable then there would have been a race condition, in which case you could use theading.Lock to avoid it.